# Adding new row to dataframe with group by and summarise

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, tidyr

I want to group my df by three columns and add a new row which will be a sum of a fourth column.

My data looks like

```
fc <- c("F", "F", "E", "E", "TF", "TF")
group_code <- c("Egg_x", "Egg_y", "Egg_x", "Egg_y", "Egg_x", "Egg_y")
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
value <- c(2, 21, 4, 3, 20, 15)

df <-data.frame(cbind(fc, group_code, id, value))

> df
  fc group_code id value
1  F      Egg_x  1     2
2  F      Egg_y  1    21
3  E      Egg_x  1     4
4  E      Egg_y  1     3
5 TF      Egg_x  1    20
6 TF      Egg_y  1    15
```

In this example I want to create a new group which will include both `Egg_x` and `Egg_y`, I can do this using `df$group <- sub('\\_.*', '', df$group_code)`, we have

```
> df
  fc group_code id value main_group
1  F      Egg_x  1     2  Egg
2  F      Egg_y  1    21  Egg
3  E      Egg_x  1     4  Egg
4  E      Egg_y  1     3  Egg
5 TF      Egg_x  1    20  Egg
6 TF      Egg_y  1    15  Egg
```

I want to add in a new row for each value of the `fc` column wehreby I group on fc, id and main_group and get the sum of the value column.

My end df should look like:

```
> df
  fc group_code id value main_group
1  F      Egg_x  1     2  Egg
2  F      Egg_y  1    21  Egg
3  F      Egg    1    23  Egg
4  E      Egg_x  1     4  Egg
5  E      Egg_y  1     3  Egg
6  E      Egg    1     7  Egg
7 TF      Egg_x  1    20  Egg
8 TF      Egg_y  1    15  Egg
9 TF      Egg    1    35  Egg
```

In the above df every third row the value element in a sum of the previous two elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we'll create a separate dataframe with summary rows - `df_sum`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df <-
  tibble(
    fc         = c("F", "F", "E", "E", "TF", "TF"),
    group_code = c("Egg_x", "Egg_y", "Egg_x", "Egg_y", "Egg_x", "Egg_y"),
    id         = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    value      = c(2, 21, 4, 3, 20, 15)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(main_group = sub('\\_.*', '', group_code))


df_sum <-
  df %>% 
  group_by(fc, main_group, id) %>% 
  summarise(value =  sum(value)) %>% 
  mutate(group_code = main_group)

df_sum
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   fc, main_group [3]
#>   fc    main_group    id value group_code
#>   <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1 E     Egg            1     7 Egg       
#> 2 F     Egg            1    23 Egg       
#> 3 TF    Egg            1    35 Egg
```

Then we bind it to the original df and arrange

```r
res <-
  bind_rows(df, df_sum) %>% 
  # fct_inorder to make sure summary rows appear after
  # original rows after sorting
  mutate(group_code = fct_inorder(group_code)) %>% 
  arrange(fc, main_group, id, group_code) %>% 
  mutate()

res
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>   fc    group_code    id value main_group
#>   <chr> <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1 E     Egg_x          1     4 Egg       
#> 2 E     Egg_y          1     3 Egg       
#> 3 E     Egg            1     7 Egg       
#> 4 F     Egg_x          1     2 Egg       
#> 5 F     Egg_y          1    21 Egg       
#> 6 F     Egg            1    23 Egg       
#> 7 TF    Egg_x          1    20 Egg       
#> 8 TF    Egg_y          1    15 Egg       
#> 9 TF    Egg            1    35 Egg
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Bit rusty with R atm. I used ```mutate(value = sum(value), group_code = main_group)``` to retain other columns I exluded from the example

Answer (score 2):

Reshape your data frame to wide format then create a new column `Egg = Egg_x + Egg_y` and convert back to long format

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  spread(group_code, value) %>% 
  mutate(Egg = Egg_x + Egg_y) %>% 
  gather(key = "group_code", value, -fc, -id) %>% 
  arrange(fc)
#>   fc id group_code value
#> 1  E  1      Egg_x     4
#> 2  E  1      Egg_y     3
#> 3  E  1        Egg     7
#> 4  F  1      Egg_x     2
#> 5  F  1      Egg_y    21
#> 6  F  1        Egg    23
#> 7 TF  1      Egg_x    20
#> 8 TF  1      Egg_y    15
#> 9 TF  1        Egg    35
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>